# Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton on Androidx library

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout

I added a simple widget button to my Android activity:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginLeft="4sp"
    android:layout_marginTop="1sp"
    android:layout_marginRight="4sp"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <ListView
        android:id="@+id/orders_list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:focusable="auto" />

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/fab"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="end|bottom"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add"
        android:contentDescription="fazer pedido"
        android:layout_margin="16dp" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Then I get

```
android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #18: Binary XML file line #18: Error inflating class android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
```

Here are my gradle dependencies

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:3.12.1'
    implementation 'org.json:json:20190722'
    implementation 'com.fasterxml.jackson.core:jackson-databind:2.10.1'
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'
    implementation 'androidx.legacy:legacy-support-v4:1.0.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.0.0'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.0'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.1.1'
}
```

I tried all solutions here on stackoverflow. Some mentions using backgroundTint but I don't even use that. Some others mention about v7 compact library, but I'm using androidx one. So this problem looks like a new one, different from others

Don't know if it helps but this is my activity:

```
public class OrdersActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AbsListView.OnScrollListener{
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_orders);
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You should use a Floating Button from the Google library. In order to do it, you must first add the library in your dependencies file. Here's the line of code :

```
implementation "com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha3"
```

Then, in your XML file, replace :

```
 <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
```

with

```
<com.google.android.material.floatingactionbutton.FloatingActionButton
```

Comment: This solves the problem, but it'd be nice to know  why it happened, since I used that example from the official android documetation and there was no deprecated advice

Comment: After some research, I found this official Android link that explains how to migrate from the Support Library (where the original Floating Button was) to AndroidX. In your case, the package _com.android.support:design_ now became **com.google.android.material:material-rc01**, so I think that it is the new way to include Floating Buttons in new Android projects.

Here's the link showing the new AndroidX packages : https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/migrate/artifact-mappings